# phpMyAdmin malformed datetime

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying this example query

```
SELECT '2008-12-31 23:59:59' + INTERVAL 1 SECOND;
```

from the manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

and as result:

```
'2008-12-31 23:59:59' + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
323030392d30312d30312030303a30303a3030
```

(first row being column name, second row being first result row)

I tried this directly on the mysql database and it works fine. How can i fix this?

MySQL Server version: 5.1.49
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.49
phpMyAdmin version: 4.0.9

Comment: That's the Hex representation of the ASCII encoding of the correct result `2009-01-01 00:00:00`. No idea why it ends up showing you that.